# Conditional data-binds in KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a custom binding handler on a `<tbody>` that I only want to apply if the user has the proper permissions from the Viewmodel. This data-bind allows the user to drag and drop elements in the table to re-order the list.

Is it possible to conditionally data-bind my custom binding handler if certain conditions are met?

Basically I want:

```
<tbody data-bind="if (hasPermission){custom-binding: list}"></tbody>
```

Is this sort of behavior possible to implement with knockout? I think there are other strategies I can employ like have a button that allows the user to sort the table (that only shows up if he has the right permission), but I wanted to check if there are any other approaches.

Thanks.

***EDIT***

I don't feel good about the solution I came up with but it allowed me to get the results I wanted:

```html
        <!--ko if: hasPermission-->
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: list, sortableList: list">
            @Html.Partial("_FilesTabTableBody")
        </tbody>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!--ko if: !hasPermission()-->
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: list">
            @Html.Partial("_FilesTabTableBody")
        </tbody>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

Essentially I'm just duplicating the HTML in two places..it's not pretty but it does thoe job. Thanks to everyone for their input.

Comment: I just wonder, after you made the edit, do you know serverside if the user has permission? Because then you could just render the appropriate html server side.

Comment: It's a good intuition. the hasPermission actually changes when the user interacts with the list, so I can't do it all using templated HTML. Good thought though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about a custom binding is that you have full control.  In your custom binding, you could add another parameter that controls how the binding behaves.  For example, you could create a visible binding that is only honored when another observable is true:

```
var vm = function() {
    var me = this;

    me.canChangeVisible = ko.observable(true);
    me.showMessage = ko.observable(true);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: canChangeVisible">Can Change Visible</input></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showMessage">Show Message</input></div>
</div>
<div data-bind="makeVisible: showMessage, basedOn: canChangeVisible">Message</div>
```

In your custom binding, look at the "basedOn" to see if it should be used:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.makeVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var bo = allBindings.get('basedOn');
        var canChange = bo == null ? true : ko.unwrap(bo);
        if( canChange )
            ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

Here's a complete [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/2CW6G/) showing this.  The setting of the "Show Message" checkbox is only used if "Can Change Visible" is checked.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a virtual element.

```html
<!-- ko if: hasPermission -->
<tbody data-bind="custom-binding: list"></tbody>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to keep the <tbody> node no matter what, I just don't want it to have that custom-binding under some circumstances. The tbody also has a data-bind: foreach to enumerate all the rows in the list.

Comment: It would be cleanest if your view model would not contain any items if the user has no permission to see them. Therefore it's the Wrong Thing to do this in in the view anyway. A computed might work, but actually your API should not even return those items at all. Obfuscating stuff the user isn't supposed to see to begin with is not a good strategy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think we might have a missing communication. I want to allow the users to see the elements in this list, I just don't want them to be able to re-order them unless they have the permission to. That's the scenario.

Comment: Ah, all-right. I'd probably use a custom binding `sortable: hasPermission` in this case.

Comment: What do you have as an alternative for users that don't have the permission, do you still use the same `list`? Could you combine @Tomalak's answer with a `<!-- ifnot: hasPermission --><tbody data-bind="foreach: list">...</tbody><!-- /ko -->`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed..?

```
<tbody data-bind="custom-binding: safeList"></tbody>

vm.safeList = ko.computed(function() {
    if (vm.hasPermission) return vm.list;
    return undefined; // or whatever you do when user has no permission
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me get started. The custom binding uses jquery UI to make rows in the table drag and dropable. I still ALSO have a foreach binding on that node to enumerate all the rows. If my custom binding handler is applied to the <tbody> with undefined, I believe it will still allow the user to drag and drop rows.

Comment: In that case, you could make another computed for your foreach binding that will return an empty array (or whatever) when the user does not have permission.